# Can I create a bookmarklet that adds a parameter to redirects

Tags: javascript, redirect, parameters, bookmarklet

## Is it possible to create a bookmarklet or script to add a parameter to redirects and maybe links?

I've tried:

```js
javascript:window.onbeforeunload = function(e) { return e + "?myparam" }
```

Is is possible to do this?

#### Thanks,

DerDer56

Answer (score 0):

This bookmarklet will add a `myparam` parameter to each link on a page:

```
javascript:(function () {for (i = 0; i < document.links.length; ++i) {document.links[i].href += '?&myparam'}})()
```

Formatted, that is:

```js
(function () {

    // analyze each of the page’s links
    for (let i = 0; i < document.links.length; ++i) {

        // for each of the page’s links, add the
        // `myparam` parameter, but precede it with
        // both `?` and `&` so it also works on links
        // that already have parameters
        document.links[i].href += '?&myparam'
    }
}
)()
```

After clicking the bookmarklet from a browser, a link to:

- `https://example.com` becomes `https://example.com/?&myparam` and
- `https://example.com/search?q=query` becomes `https://example.com/search?q=query?&myparam`

Comment: I already figured that part out, but is there a way to add it to redirects?

Comment: @derder56 It depends on what you mean by “redirects”. Do you mean links on a page that don’t take you directly to your destination, but route you through a URL shortener?

Comment: location.href or location.replace redirects.

Comment: Do you mean a bookmarklet that will, itself, work on a page with `javascript:` links? Can you give an example of a page where you want what you’re looking for?